# Cannot manipulate right margins/position of carousel indicators

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently fiddling around with some bootstrap elements, and I'm trying to make my carousel's indicators float right and also I wanted to change their orientation/alignment from horizontal (default as you see them now) to vertical (90 degrees z-index possibly?). Imagine a faux-pas 'scrollbar' made out of them.

Here is my current code: http://jsfiddle.net/kmhfq4x1/1/

A relevant note:

I wanted to purposely make and keep the carousel slides as large in size as the viewable area in the page at any given time, which forced me to tack on a `position: fixed;` attribute on the respective parent containers, but from what I'm reading this might just be the inherent problem.

I'm hoping there's a way to do both. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your css:

```
.carousel-indicators{
   top: 50%;
   right: 10px;
   left: initial;
}
.carousel-indicators li {
    display:block;
}
.carousel-indicators{

    width: auto;
}
```

I hope this is what you wanted.
Here is a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fmanfgy3/).